# External API Data Displays In Browser Console, Undefined In Page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Please, I am in dire need of your assistance. I am trying to fetch data from an external API using axios in NextJS (Reactjs)/TypeScript using getServerSideProps. Data fetch is okay and json is returned server-side in console.log . This data also displays as json client-side. However, displaying this on the page has been a nightmare! It simply returns 'undefined'. Please, help me identify what I am doing wrong.

```js
import NextLink from "next/link";
import { GetServerSideProps, NextPage } from "next";
import { InferGetServerSidePropsType } from 'next'
import ErrorPage from "next/error";
import axios from 'axios';
import EmployeeList from '../components/employees/EmployeeList'
import Card from '../components/ui/Card';
import { ReactNode, useEffect, useState} from 'react';

interface Data {
  customAttributes?: {};
  dateOfBirth?: number;
  dateOfJoining?: number;
  designation?: string;
  email?: string;
  employeeID?: string;
  employeeType?: string;
  gender?: string;
  location?: string;
  name?: string;
  payGrade?: string;
  status?: string;
  teams?: [string];
};

interface dataContainer {
  totalItems: number;
  size: number;
  totalPages: number;
  pageNumber: number;
  responseObject: 
   {
    employeeID?: string;
    name?: string;
    email?: string;
    employeeType?: string;
    dateOfBirth?: number;
    gender?: string;
    dateOfJoining?: number;
    designation?: string;
    payGrade?: string;
    location?: string;
    teams?: [string];
    status?: string;
    customAttributes?: {};
   }[]
 
}

const Home: NextPage<{ getEmployee: dataContainer }> = (props) => {
  const empData = props ;

  const [employeeDetails, setEmployeeDetails] = useState<dataContainer>();

  if (!empData) {
    return <ErrorPage statusCode={404} />;
  }

/**
 * 
 * Removing unwanted patterns in JSON data (client-side), in order to 
 * be able to parse it as a json data. However, this has been done
 * server-side in getServerSideProps, so there's no need to do it 
 * client-side again (I thought!).
 *   
 */
  var empData2 = JSON.stringify(empData) 
  const empData3 = empData2.replace(/\\/g,'')
  const empData4 = empData3.replace(/""/g,'')
  const empData5 = empData4.trim()
  const empData6: dataContainer = JSON.parse(empData5)


  useEffect(() => {setEmployeeDetails(empData6)},[])
  

  console.log('API Client-Side Data Rendering...', empData);

  return (

    // <EmployeeList employees={employeeDetails} />

    <div >
    <ul >
      {props?.getEmployee.responseObject?.map((employee, idx) : any => {
        <li>
          <div key={idx}>
            <div >
              <h3> Employee: {employee?.employeeID} {employee.name} </h3>
              <p> Email: {employee?.email}</p>
            </div>
            <button>Show Details</button>
          </div>
        </li>
      })}
    </ul>
    </div>

    );
};

  export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async () => {

    var data = JSON.stringify([]);
    var getEmployee: string ;
    var text: dataContainer ;
    
    var config = {
      method: 'get',
      url: 'https://subd.dsite.com/module-apis/relevance/873432/smodule?page=0&size=20',
      headers: { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
        'Accept': 'application/json', 
        'Authorization': 'Basic 87454024-ADJFEKKER-ADFENGGA-9834442'
      },
      data : data
    };
    
    const result = await axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
      return JSON.stringify(response.data)   
    })
    // .then((getEmployee) => {getEmployee.json()})
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });

//  Edit incoming API data to conform to JSON object format 
    const data4 = JSON.stringify(result)
    const data5 = data4.replace(/\\/g,'')
    const data6 = data5.replace(/[\r\n]/gm, '')
    const data7 = data6.replace(/"{/g,'{')
    const data8 = data7.replace(/}"/g,'}')
    const data9: dataContainer = await JSON.parse(data8)


const mergeData = data9 

return {
      props:  {mergeData}
    };

    };

export default Home;

const EMPLOYEE_DATA: dataContainer = {
  totalItems: 0,
  size: 0,
  totalPages: 0,
  pageNumber: 0,
  responseObject: [
   {
    customAttributes: {},
    dateOfBirth: 0,
    dateOfJoining: 0,
    designation: '',
    email: 'mccarthybrian377343@gmail.com',
    employeeID: '98343113343',
    employeeType: '',
    gender: 'FEMALE',
    location: '',
    name: 'John Doe',
    payGrade: '',
    status: '',
    teams: [''],
   },
   {
    customAttributes: {},
    dateOfBirth: 0,
    dateOfJoining: 0,
    designation: '',
    email: 'mccarthybrian377343@gmail.com',
    employeeID: 'AH98343113343',
    employeeType: '',
    gender: 'MALE',
    location: '',
    name: 'Tomi Oyebade',
    payGrade: '',
    status: '',
    teams: [''],
   },
   {
    customAttributes: {},
    dateOfBirth: 0,
    dateOfJoining: 0,
    designation: '',
    email: 's.oludunsin@yahoo.com',
    employeeID: 'PJ98343113343',
    employeeType: '',
    gender: 'FEMALE',
    location: '',
    name: 'Sosthenes Oludunsin',
    payGrade: '',
    status: '',
    teams: [''],
   },
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the output of logging `empData` to the console?

Comment: [Fast Refresh] done in 608ms hot-dev-client.js:135:16
API Client-Side Data Rendering... 
Object { mergeData: {…} }
index.tsx:50:13
API Client-Side Data Rendering...  
Object { mergeData: {…} }
react_devtools_backend.js:4082:31
API Client-Side Data Rendering... 
Object { mergeData: {…} }
index.tsx:50:13
API Client-Side Data Rendering...  
Object { mergeData: {…} }
react_devtools_backend.js:4082:31

Comment: Many thanks, @juliomalves. The above was the best I could do. I didn't know how to copy it perfectly. However, the other thing I was able to infer from this platform is that de-structuring props as argument to the component works. I re-created the page as a JS file and DE-STRUCTURED props, it works fine. The challenge I currently have is how to type the de-structured props props in the page component, as the project is a Typescript project. I sincerely appreciate the time you gave to this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to stringify the data after parsing it the first time.

```
const data9: dataContainer = await JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data8))
{ prop: data9 }
```

Comment: Thanks so much, @ninsau, for your response. I did precisely what you said. However, it came up with 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token t in JSON at position 16; Call Stack JSON parse'. It was that same situation that led to having to edit the data with regular expressions in order to conform to the json format, in the first instance. Many thanks to you, for being there.